# Xcode dies on attempt to open account under preferences, issue with development certificates?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine, ios-provisioning

I'm attempting my first IOS build from Unity 3d.

Here's some of the output from the dump after Xcode dies.  I've done a fetch/retrieve of a new developer certificate, and it seems valid in the keychain.  I've also removed all old provisioning profiles from the IOS device (iphone 4S) attached.  I tried removing Xcode and reinstalling it to no avail.  The iphone actually does actually show up under Window->Devices in xcode.  When I right click on the iphone in the device list and look at provisioning profiles I get the following:
iostpp:com.jaqen2525.hb1 Ad Hoc
iostpp:com.jaqen2525.hb1 Dev
and two others that I'm not using: so the new provisioning profiles are there, and the development certificate under the keychain looks fine, though there is one that is not quite working:
Lee Bererton's CA: This root certificate is not trusted. So I trusted it in my keychain access by right clicking and getting Info, then clicking on choosing to trust it.

Also of note, any attempt under Xcode->Preferences->Account, then opening up the provisioning profiles consistently crashes Xcode
Xcode still crashing, any thoughts?

```
Process:               Xcode [1244]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.2 (6776)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-6776000000000000~11
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       811890240
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [1244]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-03-13 13:23:31.081 -0600
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.2 (14C1510)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        4F9FAC01-C04A-5ECE-C8B8-4E1F44F3E7C5


Time Awake Since Boot: 4700 seconds

Crashed Thread:        17

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 6C131e
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-6760/DVTFoundation/DeveloperStructure/DVTExtendedPlatformInfo.m:39
Details:  No Xcode.DVTFoundation.ExtendedPlatformInfo extension provided for platform 'com.apportable.platform.android'
Object:   <DVTExtendedPlatformInfo>
Method:   +extendedPlatformInfoForPlatformIdentifier:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7ff48e8c78f0>{number = 26, name = (null)}
Hints:   None
Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010a6a81aa -[IDEAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1  0x000000010945f18f _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010945f47e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x000000010947c316 +[DVTExtendedPlatformInfo extendedPlatformInfoForPlatformIdentifier:] (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x000000010947d374 -[DVTPlatform(DVTExtendedPlatformInfo) dvt_extendedInfo] (in DVTFoundation)
  5  0x00000001134974b1 -[DTDKProvisioningProfile dvt_platform] (in DTDeviceKitBase)
  6  0x0000000109444860 DVTProvisioningProfileAllowsEntitlements (in DVTFoundation)
  7  0x000000010945b259 __216+[DVTCodesignResolver parametersForTeamID:bundleIdentifier:entitlements:requiredFeatures:applicableSigningIdentityCertificates:platform:requiredCodesignableDevices:requiresProfile:profileManager:logAspect:withError:]_block_invoke459 (in DVTFoundation)
  8  0x0000000109303f76 -[NSSet(DVTNSSetAdditions) dvt_setByFilteringUsingBlock:] (in DVTFoundation)
  9  0x0000000109459eab +[DVTCodesignResolver parametersForTeamID:bundleIdentifier:entitlements:requiredFeatures:applicableSigningIdentityCertificates:platform:requiredCodesignableDevices:requiresProfile:profileManager:logAspect:withError:] (in DVTFoundation)
 10  0x000000010945955d +[DVTCodesignResolver parametersForTeamID:certificateKind:bundleIdentifier:entitlements:requiredFeatures:limitSearchToKeychain:platform:requiredCodesignableDevices:requiresProfile:certificateUtilities:withError:] (in DVTFoundation)
 11  0x0000000112eb9a46 +[XCCodeSignContext codesignParameterSnapshotWithMacroExpansionScope:emitWarnings:certificateUtilities:error:] (in DevToolsCore)
 12  0x0000000112eb9f76 +[XCCodeSignContext prepareForCodeSigningWithMacroExpansionScope:certificateUtilities:] (in DevToolsCore)
 13  0x0000000112e2641e -[XCProductTypeSpecification computeDependenciesWithMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
 14  0x0000000112ecb8eb -[XCNativeTargetDGSnapshot(DependencyGraphCreation) computeDependenciesWithMacroExpansionScope:] (in DevToolsCore)
 15  0x0000000112da43fa -[PBXTargetBuildContext createDependencyGraphWithTargetDGSnapshot:] (in DevToolsCore)
 16  0x0000000112dc1e0a -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) dg_setTargetSnapshot:] (in DevToolsCore)
 17  0x0000000112dc09a8 -[PBXTargetBuildContext(DependencyGraphEvents) processDependencyGraphEvents] (in DevToolsCore)
 18  0x0000000112e1dd60 -[XCBlockQueue _processNextBlockInThreadSlotNumber:] (in DevToolsCore)
 19  0x0000000112e1e030 -[XCBlockQueue _processBlocksInThreadSlotNumber:] (in DevToolsCore)
 20  0x00007fff883b990a __NSThread__main__ (in Foundation)
 21  0x00007fff93ae0268 _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 22  0x00007fff93ae01e5 _pthread_body (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 23  0x00007fff93ade41d thread_start (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)

abort() called

Application Specific Signatures:
((void *)0) != platformInfo

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9357a4de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9357964f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8bbaab34 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8bba9ffb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8bba9858 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8fca2aef RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8fca286a ReceiveNextEventCommon + 431
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8fca26ab _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8642ef81 _DPSNextEvent + 964
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8642e730 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 194
10  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x00000001099c6d3d -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 237
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff86422593 -[NSApplication run] + 594
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8640da14 NSApplicationMain + 1832
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff9342e5c9 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff93580232 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff935a8a6a _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9357a4de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9357964f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8bbaab34 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8bba9ffb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8bba9858 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fff9435fc80 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 434
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff883b990a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93ae0268 _pthread_body + 131
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93ae01e5 _pthread_start + 176
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93ade41d thread_start + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9357a4de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9357964f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8bbaab34 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8bba9ffb __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8bba9858 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff883bb849 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 278
6   com.apple.DTDeviceKitBase       0x0000000113465df8 -[DTDKRemoteDeviceDataListener listenerThreadImplementation] + 970
7   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff883b990a __NSThread__main__ + 1345
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93ae0268 _pthread_body + 131
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93ae01e5 _pthread_start + 176
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93ade41d thread_start + 13

Thread 4:: com.apple.CFSocket.private
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9357f3fa __select + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93ae0268 _pthread_body + 131
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93ae01e5 _pthread_start + 176
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff93ade41d thread_start + 13
```

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the android plugin for Sprite Builder. A quick fix until the plugin has been updated is to uninstall it. Navigate to /Library in Finder or the Terminal. Remove the directory called SBAndroid or SBAndroidStarter. Try starting xcode and it should be working again.

Keep an eye on this [issue](http://forum.spritebuilder.com/t/xcode-6-2-beta-crash/3185/12) on Github and this [thread](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-spritebuilder/issues/1255) on the Sprite Builder forums. Hopefully they can fix it soon.

Answer (score 1):

Quit your xcode and delete plist file /Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.*

this worked for me :)

if its not worked for you then remove /Library/Preferences/SBAndroidStarter folder

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the latest SpriteBuilder Android Plugin fixed this for me